# How to create a symbol with no fill color in qgis?

Tags: qgis, style, symbology

Where can I find a simple circle to draw it around a point feature. I can change symbol fill color as well as symbol border color. But I didn't find a way to set fill color to no color.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the alpha channel of the fill color to 0.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

in the symbol properties, you can change the symbol type from "Fill" to "Border: simple line". This way you do not have a fill. (I am sorry if these are not the exact name, but I am translating from a non English version. However I'm sure that you can find it)

Answer (score 3):

you can just make the opacity of the stroke color zero

[image]
[image]